# How much attack would I have?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

How high would the Attack be after I had a +1 Boost? For example, my Garchomp knows Swords Dance which raises the Attack by +2 and my Garchomp has 358 Attack as his stat and it goes up by 50 when Mega-Evolved, making it 408. Say I Mega Evolved and used Swords Dance, how much would it go up by? 100? And if it is a percentage, what is the percentage of +2? I'd also like to know the percentage of +1 please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These +/- boosts are called Stages, which are in-battle modifier for stats. Stages go from -6 to +6 and, from Generation III to now, have the following multiplier effect on stats:

```
| -6  | -5  | -4  | -3  | -2  | -1  | 0 |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |
| 2/8 | 2/7 | 2/6 | 2/5 | 1/2 | 2/3 | 1 | 3/2 |  2  | 5/2 |  3  | 7/2 |  4  |
```

However, these modifiers only apply to Attack, Defense, Special Attack, Special Defense, and Speed. In battle, your Pokemon also have Accuracy and Evasion stats, which follow different multipliers. As of Generation V, they are:

```
| -6  | -5  | -4  | -3  | -2  | -1  | 0 |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |
| 1/3 | 3/8 | 3/7 | 1/2 | 3/5 | 3/4 | 1 | 4/3 | 5/3 |  2  | 7/3 | 8/3 |  3  |
```

Thus for your example, your Mega Garchomp's Attack of 408 with a +2 boost would result in an Attack of 816.